# Magento 2 Header Sign In Sign Out Issue on CMS pages

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I have a strange issue in Magento 2. After successfully logged in it redirected to My account page and working fine as per Magento 2 standard.

The issue raised after going to CMS pages. It still shows sign in link in header while I have already logged in.

In other pages, its working fine e.g. on product, category, homepage...

The issue only appears in CMS pages.

I have faced this issue In Magento 1 and resolved it by Hole punching. But I have no idea how can do it in Magento2.

what could be the issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Faced this issue with Magento's default full page caching? OR Had you installed any third-party extension for caching?

Comment: I am facing with default Magento.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this without breaking cache?